# how to set 3 numbers dynamically in conference in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, conference

I have a dialplan which takes incoming call from User1 and forward it to other User2.
I want to apply a confrence when user1 calls it should be forwaded to User2 and after pressing a dtmf by User2 then User1 and User 2 should enter into confrence with User3
Is it possible,I know [there](http://astbook.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html/asterisk-book.html#asterisk-CHP-6-SECT-7.3) is a Meetme() function but i cant find how to set the user dynamically

Below is the sample code (in order to understand what i want to do)

```
exten =>101,1,Answer()
exten =>101,n,Playback(welcome)
exten =>101,n,Dial(DADHI/User2)
exten =>2,1,Dial(DADHI/User3) ;on pressing dtmf 2 by user2 this line will execute
exten =>2,n,Meetme(8060)
```

Is the above code correct way to take users into conference.Correct me if i am wrong.

And if anybody have any solution to the above problem please do help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no easy way do that.

That require create new call.

You can get some ideas from this article

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO

Comment: i dint ask for an easy way,i asked dialing the users then taking them in conference is a correct way or not.Anyway thanks for the link it really helped.